# Aligning 270 degree oriented div (transform: rotate)

Tags: html, css, transform

I have a div (tab) that I rotate 270 degrees like so:

```
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%; 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
```

(Example here: http://users.telenet.be/prullen/align.html)

When I want to align the tab with the top edge of the content box, it's pretty easy. i just set "top" to "3px" (the border size). However, for the bottom it's another story.

It appears I need to calculate this with jquery like so:

```
$tab.css('bottom', (Math.abs($tab.outerWidth()-$tab.outerHeight())
```

(Though for this example I'm just using a static value. It may not look exactly like I want it to in your browser, here's an image: )

[image]

I was wondering if there is a better way since this does not seem to work all that well in firefox for example (1 pixel shift). Is there an easier way by adjusting the transform-origin perhaps?

(Note that I need to keep the same div structure I have now)

Ideally it'd be as easy as setting bottom to: 3px (the border thickness)

Thanks.

Comment: This question would be much easier to answer and explain if you instead put only the relevant HTML and CSS into a jsfiddle for people to fork and edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to put the tab at the top of the sticky, apply the class `.tab-top` to the `.sticky-tab` element.

```
.tab-top {
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    top: 5px; /*Border Size*/
    right: 5px; /*Border Size*/
}
```

When you want to put the tab at the bottom of the sticky, apply the class `.tab-bottom` to the `.sticky-tab` element.

```
.tab-bottom {
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(100%);
    bottom: 0;
    right: -18px; /*Height (appearing as width once rotated) of the tab*/
}
```

Essentially you want to change the transform origin to be at the bottom right-hand corner of the element and then attach the element to the bottom of its parent. This will place the element exactly below the `.sticky`. Then use the `translateX(100%)` to force the bottom of the `.sticky-tab` to align with the bottom of the `.sticky`.

Comment: If you port your example to a jsfiddle, I will happily provide a working example of this answer in another jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Can you tell me though, what if I want the tab on the right side of the screen. What does the origin need to be then? I tried playing with it but nothing seems to work. (If you want I can create a fiddle)

Comment: @Wesley I would imagine that the origin would need to be the bottom left-hand corner, so `transform-origin: 0% 100%;`? You may also need to adjust the `top`, `bottom`, and `right` properties. If you end up not being able to figure it out, create a fiddle and I'll take a look.